# Cascading Dropdown in MVC4?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi i have two Drodowns in my view. **CustomerName** and **Contactperson**.if i select the CustomerName the CustomerName related ContactPerson have to load automatically in ContactPerson dropdown.I did this task. its perfectly working.

My output is will come same as like which is mentioned in the below image.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ba2P.jpg)

Now i what i need is i would like to change the format of output.

[Have to change in this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/042FS.jpg)

I need to change my output format same as like which is mention in the second image . That is if i select the value in dropdown means each dropdown  contain First value as Please select . I need this in each dropdown. I tried many ways but i didn't get correct solution for my code . please any one give me solution for this task..

**My Controller Code**

```
  public JsonResult GetCustomers()
    {
        return Json(db.Customers.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

   public JsonResult GetContactPersobByCustomerId(string customerId)
    {
        Guid Id = Guid.Parse(customerId);
        var customercontacts = (from a in db.CustomerContacts where a.CustomerID == Id select a);
        return Json(customercontacts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**My ViewCode**

```
  @Html.Label("Customer Name", new { @class = "control-label" })
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a Customer", new { @class = "form-control required", type = "text" })

 @Html.Label("Contact Person", new { @class = "control-label" })
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerContactID, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a ContactPerson", new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "CustomerContactID" })
```

**My Json Code**

```
  <script>
    $(function () {
    $.ajax(
   '@Url.Action("GetCustomers", "VisitorsForm")',{
            type: "GET",
            datatype: "Json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('#CustomerID').append('<option value="' + value.CustomerID + '">' + value.DisplayName + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });


          $('#CustomerID').change(function () {
        $('#CustomerContactID').empty();

        $.ajax(
             '@Url.Action("GetContactPersobByCustomerId", "VisitorsForm")',{
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "Json",
                data: { CustomerID: $('#CustomerID').val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                 $('#CustomerContactID').append('<option value="' + value.CustomerContactID + '">' + value.ContactReference + '</option>');

              });
            }
         });
     });
 });
```

This is coding is perfectly working and gave output as per i mentioned in the first image. Now i need to change this output to second image format. I tried many code but no use. please any one give me suggestion.

Advance thanks.

Comment: Just add `$('#CustomerContactID').append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select'));` immediately before `$.each`

Comment: you mean $('#CustomerContactID').append($('<option></option>).val('').text('Please select'));`  $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                 $('#CustomerContactID').append('<option value="' + value.CustomerContactID + '">' + value.ContactReference + '</option>'); like this stephen

Comment: Yes. And note also that the first dropdownlist should not be loaded using ajax and suggest you also study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym)

Comment: Stephen Im getting error [Error][2] just see this



  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kqwXF.jpg

Comment: Your missing the `'` after `('<option><option>`

Comment: ok i have a try again

Comment: Note also you should include `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` for each of the properties (so you get the error message)

Comment: And you should not be returning all properties of `CustomerContacts ` in the controller method - your just degrading performance by sending a whole lot of extra information to the client that you never use. Return a collection of anonymous objects instead.

Comment: Stephen its working Thank you soo much but i have one doubt that is you mentioned that first dropdown should not be loaded usinf ajax. can you explain me what is  your suggestion is? I am new to MVC ajax jquery so can you tell my mistake that i did..

Comment: Stephen how to return a collection of amonymous object?? im new to mvc so any links ??

Comment: Just study the code in the DotNetFiddle I linked to. If your editing an existing object, or need to return the view because `ModelState` is invalid, then the correct `CustomerID` and `CustomerContactID` will not be selected (only the first "Please select" option will be selected so the poor user has to select them all over again)